# Logstash metrics event rate example

Tags: configuration, logstash

I'm trying to figure out what a proper example configuration for the logstash metrics plugin should look like. (Using logstash 1.4.2)

The [original from the documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/metrics#example-computing-event-rate) isn't even passing the configtest :( ... so that's what I come up with so far:

```
input {
  generator 
    type => "generated"
    count => 10
  }
}
filter {
  metrics {
    meter => [ "events" ]
    add_tag => "metric"
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => line {
      format => "rate: %{events.rate_1m}"
    }
  }
}
```

My expected output is sth. like:

```
rate: 23721.983566819246
```

But what I actually get is (10 times of course):

```
rate: %{events.rate_1m}
```

Any hints are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution myself.

Note to self ... the regular events and the metrics events have to be treaded differently.

The output configuration has to be kept within a proper condition like this:

```
output {
  if "metric" in [tags] {
    stdout {
      codec => line {
        format => "rate: %{events.rate_1m}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```